# Is it possible to show a custom typescript error in VS code when an interface is used improperly?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to explain to myself (in the future lol) how exactly a function should be implemented, It would be nice if I could get the UI to tell me what EXACTLY I need to return instead of what I shouldn't return. Given:

```
type ruleFunction = (this: Rule, dev: Developer) => 'submitResultsFunction'

const foo: ruleFunction = (dev: Developer) => {}
```

currently shows: "Type '(this: Rule, dev: Developer => void' is not assignable to type 'ruleFunction'

I would like to replace that text with 'function must return 'submitResultsFunction'

Comment: I don't believe so. The closest I've seen is a conditional type that includes `never` so it will always raise a type error: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=3.9.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgrgZ2AewLYFEBOnmYDwAqANLMgHZKYCGAlmcCVjplBAB7ARkAmCUldAOYA+KAF4oBVhy69SFYNTrAoAfklQAXFADerbLm1NcJAPrayEAG4RMAXwBQDgMbkkUKtvhI0x-ALJBEjI4VAAjWxIAcmAACxo+ACV0AEEAGTSATShLCDkUKAiPHNCIzCjRCSiqMOcohwB6BslwaCiAIhrndqioBJzkFSoEBBpBMhqAG2gC0EgoKL1bZm12uP7k9KyciDy+AqKqEvDbdoBuKHMdm0wLuyiAOiA But to be honest, it's a bit of a hack.

Comment: Also, I should add that the approach I mentioned may obfuscate how you might fix it. Comparing the actual vs the expected function signature is how you would debug errors like these. This method of adding a custom message hides the original error and surfaces a different one entirely. Which, if the types are even a little bit complex, might makes things worse, not better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jsdoc notation.
For example

```js
type Fn = (arg: number) => string

/**
 * 
 * @description Function do something
 * @returns {string} Fn must return `sdf` string
 */
const myFunction: Fn = (arg) => 'sdf'
```

When you hover mouse on the `myFunction`, You will see VS code tooltip.

Documentation for `jsdoc` in typescript [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html)